# Continuity of $f(x)$ involving infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$f(x)= \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x(1-x)}$

How can I define $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ to make $f(x)$ continuous on $[0,1]$?

I've found that the limit at $0 = \pi$, and the limit from the left at $1 = \infty$.

I understand that if $f(0)=\pi$ then $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1)$, but must I define $f(1)=\infty$? Would that make $f(x)$ continuous?

EDIT: Also, can someone explain why $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin\pi x}{x} = \pi$?

Comment: Did you calculate the limit of the function as $x \to 1$? You have noticed that the denominator approaches $0$ as $x \to 1$. What about the numerator?

Comment: The limit at $1$ is not $\infty$.

Comment: I think I'm having some trouble with the rules of sin limits. I see now that the limit at the top approaches 0 as well, which would make the limit 1? What I did to find the limit at 1 (incorrectly) was I separated the function and found the limits as x->1 of $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ and $\frac{\pi}{x-1}$, and multiplied the two. If I did this incorrectly, does that mean the limit as x->0 of $\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x}$ doesn't equal $\pi$?

Comment: You cannot separate the x that way, since x is part of the argument (angle) in $sin( \ pi x)$. Continuity means that limits from the left and right at a point p are equal to each other, and both are equal to the value of the function at p. Have you worked with the limit of $\frac {sinx}{x}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Yes, I know that  the limit as  $x→0  \frac{sinx}{x} = 1$. Since my separation was incorrect, how can I show that the lim as x->0 of $\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x(1-x)} = \pi$?

Comment: Try a change of variable, like $\pi x:=u$

Comment: When you rewrite with the $u$, you will get an expression of the type $\frac {sinu}{u}$ times some constant in the denominator.

Comment: With that u, the expression would be $\frac{sinu}{(u/\pi)*(1-(u/\pi))}$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct. Now  you have a ratio $ \frac {sinu}{u}$ times something else, and you only need to now work with the something else part, or if it makes it easier, go back over the change of variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are interested in $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sin \pi x}{1-x}$.  If we let $y=1-x$, this becomes $$\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin \pi (1-y)}{y}=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin (\pi -\pi y)}{y}=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin \pi y}{y}$$

Comment: I would consider $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$ to be more basic than using the addition formula, because it amounts to reflecting across the vertical axis.  Alternatively, combining $\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ would work, and these can be more readily seen than the addition formula.  That's nothing against this answer; the nice thing about the addition formula is that it can be specialized to prove most other identities of $\sin$.

Comment: I don't know if you cancelled somehow, but the denominator is actually x(1-x).

Comment: @BKaylor:  But near x=1 that term doesn't cause a problem.  I just focused on the terms that do.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer:  Good point.  I think that is better.  This is what came to mind at the time.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: I understand, since it approaches 1. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x(1-x)} = \pi = \lim_{x\to1} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x(1-x)}.
$$
Both can be readily shown by L'Hopital's rule.

Notice that the two limits have to be equal because of symmetry: If you let $u = 1-x$, then $x$ becomes $1-u$, and $\sin(\pi x)$ becomes $\sin(\pi(1-u))$, which is the same as $\sin(\pi u)$ by a trigonometric identity.

There are various ways to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.  Once you've done that, then you can write
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \pi \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} = \pi \lim_{x\to0}  \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} = \pi \lim_{w\to0}  \frac{\sin(w)}{w},
$$
where $w= \pi x$.  Notice that as $x\to 0$, $w$ also approaches $0$, thus justifying the part that says "$w\to0$".

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Can you expand on the limit as x ->1 in the first equation? How can you algebraically show that it $=\pi$?

Comment: Also, because of this, the Intermediate Value Theorem cannot be applied since f(a)=f(b) on [a,b], correct?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on your edit:

We start with $\frac {\sin(\pi x)}{x}$ , then we do a change of variable, say, $u:= \pi x$, and we get:

$$\frac {\sin u}{u/\pi}=\frac {\pi\sin u}{u}=\pi \frac{\sin u}{u}$$